# How to echo this specific value from a Database

Tags: php, sql, echo

I'm trying to echo out a specific value, but whenever I run the code- all I get is
**nothing**.

My code is here:

```
$studentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $alias WHERE FBID=$user") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($studentname))
{
  $queried_name = $row['Name'];
  echo 'Name: ' . $queried_name;
}
```

Comment: can you var_dump($row) and confirm there is a value for 'Name' in there, and it isn't 'name' (lowercase)

Comment: Sorry- but i'm not sure how to var_dump the row. Never done that before.

Comment: just below where you have the row with `$queried_name` put `var_dump($row['Name']);`

Comment: Can you go into your mysql db, maybe with phpmysql and verify the exact naming of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$name` IS your resource handler because of this...

```
$name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $alias WHERE FBID=$user") ...
```

and the error you received is because you tried to echo the resource handler, inside your loop

```
echo ( 'Name: '.$name );
```

I understand the confusion, and I would suggest that you name your variables accordingly to avoid this. I would always name my resource handler with a prefix of `$rs` to make it clear that it is a resource.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- I tried what you said. I renamed the variable and now it doesn't output anything...

Comment: your code must be broken elsewhere.. can you vardump `$name`,`$alias` and `$user` before and after the db query?

Comment: $alias works fine. and so does $user. $name is the only one i'm having a problem with.

Comment: Thanks for all the help btw- and yes just now updated the original code in the post.

Comment: try to echo `mysql_num_rows($studentname)`?

Comment: Ha wow man. I just found the problem. Turns out that $user isn't actually being stored in the table. It just knows what $user is because it's set at the top of all of this code.

Comment: I voted your answer up- you definitely provided the most help. Look around for me here on StackOverflow- i'm sure i'll be asking more questions soon.

Answer (score 1):

`$name` is the resource handle for the MySQL connection. Use a different variable, and echo inside the loop

```
$name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $alias WHERE FBID=$user") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($name))
{
  $queried_name = $row['name'];
  echo 'Name: ' . $queried_name;

  //optionally just do
  //echo 'Name: ' . $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried what you said- but it still gave me the same output: "resource id #5"